# Catch isn't working

Tags: php, exception, try-catch

**I'm baffled. What could be causing 'catch' not to be working and how do I fix it?**

```
<?php

try {
    throw new Exception('BOOM');
    error_log("should not happen");
} catch(Exception $e) {
    error_log("should happen: " . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

### Actual output

```
[27-Apr-2010 09:43:24] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'BOOM' in /mycode/exception_problem/index.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /mycode/exception_problem/index.php on line 4
```

### Desired output

```
should happen: BOOM
```

---

PHP version 5.2.3

In php_info() I don't see anywhere exceptions could have been disabled.

I have tried with "restore_exception_handler();" but that doesn't make the catch block working.

I have also tried with "set_exception_handler(NULL);" but that neither make the catch block working.

---

**How do I get the desired output?**

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714342/catch-not-working-and-how-to-unset-the-exception-handler

Comment: Yes / NO. I wrote that post yesterday and didn't got it solved. This post is much more specific.

Comment: The post from yesterday I think I mentioned set_exception_handler(). I don't think I should have mentioned it in the code, since it seemed to confuse people. This post is just about try / throw / catch. I don't know if set_exception_handler is involved.

Comment: No, it's an exact duplicate. I updated my answer in the other question, please continue there. It does seem to have to do with error handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the posted code, called directly works as you expect.

Comment: yeah, when I run this code I get that PHP Fatal error I posted. I named the file index.php and opened via Firefox. So I guess our setups must be different, but what could be causing it?